# Found unsupported keytype (8) for nn/hadoop-kerberos@HADOOP-KERBEROS

Tags: java, authentication, hadoop, kerberos

I am trying to set up a single node Hadoop cluster in secure mode with Kerberos authentication enabled, using `hadoop-2.4.0` and `jdk1.7.0_25`.

To do so, I have created keytab files as described in documentation. While debugging things with property `HADOOP_OPTS` set with `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` I see the following error messages:

```
Found unsupported keytype (8) for nn/hadoop-kerberos@HADOOP-KERBEROS
Added key: 23version: 4
Added key: 16version: 4
Added key: 17version: 4
Added key: 18version: 4
Ordering keys wrt default_tkt_enctypes list
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 16 23 1 3.
Added key: 3version: 4
Found unsupported keytype (8) for nn/hadoop-kerberos@HADOOP-KERBEROS
Added key: 23version: 4
Added key: 16version: 4
Added key: 17version: 4
Added key: 18version: 4
Ordering keys wrt default_tkt_enctypes list
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 16 23 1 3.
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 16 23 1 3.
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=localhost UDP:3738, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=171</code></pre>
```

Please note that I have `../jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar` and 
`.../jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar` in my `CLASSPATH` variable.

Also I have the following in `kdc.conf`:

```
 [kdcdefaults]
 kdc_ports = 3738
 kdc_tcp_ports = 3738

[realms]
 HADOOP-KERBEROS = {
  kadmind_port = 3739
  #master_key_type = des3-hmac-sha1
  acl_file = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
  dict_file = /usr/share/dict/words
  #admin_keytab = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab
  admin_keytab = /etc/krb5.keytab
  supported_enctypes = aes256-cts:normal aes128-cts:normal des3-hmac-sha1:normal arcfour-hmac:normal des-hmac-sha1:normal des-cbc-md5:normal des-cbc-crc:normal des-cbc-crc:v4 des-cbc-crc:afs3
 }
[logging]
   # By default, the KDC and kadmind will log output using
   # syslog.  You can instead send log output to files like this:
   kdc = FILE:/home/build/log/krb5kdc.log
   admin_server = FILE:/home/build/log/kadmin.log
   default = FILE:/home/build/log/krb5lib.log
```

`klist -e` shows the following output for user `aleksg` which I use to run namenode with `hadoop namenode` command

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_501
Default principal: aleksg@HADOOP-KERBEROS

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
07/12/15 09:16:39  07/13/15 09:16:39  krbtgt/HADOOP-KERBEROS@HADOOP-KERBEROS
        Etype (skey, tkt): Triple DES cbc mode with HMAC/sha1, Triple DES cbc mode with HMAC/sha1 


Kerberos 4 ticket cache: /tmp/tkt501
klist: You have no tickets cached
```

So it seems that `DES cbc mode with HMAC/sha1` is being used for TGT.

Could you please point me how can I resolve the issue? Can this be somehow related to permissions of keytab files or should I regenerate keytab files with different encryption type enabled?

Thank you !

Comment: **(A1)** Sun/Oracle JDK installs with "weak key encryption" by default (because of US exports policies now obsolete); did you dowload the "unlimited strength encryption" JARs? *As long as they are in the standard directory don't worry about CLASSPATH* **(A2)** Did you try OpenJDK instead? **(B)** Some encryption algorithms may be disabled because they are deemed "weak", check your config files against http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/enctypes.html

Comment: Hi Samson. Related to A1. I have downloaded local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar and added them to the CLASSPATH. Just one question for the future , where is the standard directory that you have mentioned in your reply.
Re A2. I havn't tried OpenJDK.
Re B. I did some changes in my configuration and was able to workround the issue. Please see the answer I have just posted to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I have workarounded the issue by generating all keytab files used in configuration of secure Hadoop and which are mentioned in `hdfs-site.xml`, `yarn-site.xml`, etc. by using `des3-hmac-sha1:normal` encryption type.

```
kadmin.local -e "des3-hmac-sha1:normal"
```

Also I have changed my `krb5.conf` to use this encryption type for `default_tkt_enctypes`, `default_tgs_enctypes` and permitted_enctypes.

As well changed in `krb5kdc/kdc.conf` the `master_key_type` to `des3-hmac-sha1`.